# Dropdown list using Semantic ui and react

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic ui's dropdown in a React app. I am still at the beginning of learning React so I do not know how to proceed. I want to show a different picture depending on the selected value of the Dropdown. The picture is a React Component because it is the result of an API call. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an `onChange` event for the `dropdown`, and depending on the selected value, you can show different image.

Comment: So do I make the dropdown into a React Component and add this event to it?

Comment: Yes. And you could have a `state` to figure out which item was selected in the dropdown.